# How can AIX jfs2 snapshot size be less than size of the data on the fs?

Tags: disk-usage, aix, snapshot

On every OS I ever create the snapshots of size bigger than the occupied fs space.
For example: if I had a fs called /try of 250GB but the space used is 100GB I will create a snapshot of 100GB or a little more.
On AIX I create a snapshot with a size under the fs occupied space..and works.
On a logical volume of 2GB I create a file of 590MB

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=hello bs=1m count=590
590+0 records in
590+0 records out
```

then I create the snapshot of 256mb instead of 590MB or more

```
snapshot -o snapfrom=/try -o size=256m 
Snapshot for file system /try created on /dev/fslv00
```

df report the correct size of fs "try"

```
df -hT /try
/dev/try     jfs2    2,0G  591M    1,5G  29% /try
```

I can mount the snapshot

```
mount -o snapshot /dev/fslv00 /mnt/
```

df report size of 256mb for the snapshot but with 1,5mb used!

```
df -hT /mnt
/dev/fslv00    jfs2  256M  1,5M    255M   1% /mnt
```

For the final try I have make a md5sum check of a file..and works for both snapshot and
real fs.

```
b7fb2207c641085a9cf02064edf1742e  /mnt/hello
b7fb2207c641085a9cf02064edf1742e  /try/hello
```

The questions are simple: how can the snapshot size being under the size of the real fs? Why the space on the snapshot (1,5mb) is under the space used(591mb) of the real fs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
Is "possible" to create a snapshot with a size under the used fs size of real fs but is totally useless.
When I delete the original file /try/hello, the snapshot size become big(because of transfer of the file blocks) but because I have created it under the size of real fs, the fs become full, and the file "hello" became broken, and return i/o error.

```
df -hT /mnt
/dev/fslv00    jfs2    256M  256M     0 100% /mnt

md5sum /mnt/hello 
md5sum_64: /mnt/hello: There is an input or output error.
```